# Template compilation error when executing flush

Tags: .net, selenium, razorengine, selenium-extent-report, extent

Whenever I execute the ExtentReport.flush() method I get en exception regarding references.

I have downloaded the package using NuGet and I don't have issues compiling the code.
In another test project, it works fine. I copied the test code to the current project and nothing works.

> RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Errors while compiling a Template.
>
> Please try the following to solve the situation:
>
> - If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load 
>     the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
>     Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation.
>     See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details.
>     Currently all references have to be available as files!
>
>   - If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member': 
>       try another modelType (for example 'null' to make the model dynamic).
>       NOTE: You CANNOT use typeof(dynamic) to make the model dynamic!
>       Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types.
>       More details about the error:
> - error: (15, 11) The type or namespace name 'AventStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
>   - error: (16, 11) The type or namespace name 'AventStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   - error: (17, 11) The type or namespace name 'RazorEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   - error: (18, 11) The type or namespace name 'RazorEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   - error: (21, 65) The type or namespace name 'RazorEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   - error: (21, 101) The type or namespace name 'AventStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using AutomationClientProduct;
using AutomationReporter;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;

static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtentHtmlReporter reporter = new 
        ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\TestResults\result.html");
        ExtentReports reports = new ExtentReports();
        reports.AttachReporter(reporter);
        var logger = reports.CreateTest("New test");
        logger.Pass("Success");
        logger.Info("Succeeded test");
        logger = reports.CreateTest("Second Test");
        logger.Fail("test failed");
        reports.Flush();
}
```